# Can't run NPM or ng build, or Apache in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Yesterday i was trying to run a .sh script on ubuntu 14 and i was getting this

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
```

so i tried to fix it by running

```
sudo ln -snf /bin/env /usr/bin/env
```

That allowed me to run the sh script but not it broke all the the npm paths and i am not a linux guy so unsure how to fix it.

for npm or ng commands i get

```
-bash: /usr/bin/npm: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

or

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ng: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

i can see the error and there is no env file in /user/bin/env

It has effected everything, i cannot even start apache2

```
Failed to restart apaceh2.service: Unit apaceh2.service not found.
```

What should be there or how can i fix this? completely lost

Comment: "ubuntu 14" — Ubuntu version numbers take the form of `yy.mm` where `yy` is a two digit year and `xx` is a two digit month of release. There is no "ubuntu 14"

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check if Node.js installed on your ubuntu machine correctly.
2. You should install node-gyp before install Angular cli.

   ```
   $ sudo npm install -g node-gyp
   $ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
   ```

Comment: running npm is the issue it gives
      -bash: /usr/bin/npm: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: I don't feel this is a duplicate as the previous questions relate to windows.